# how to split up overflow-x and overflow-y

Tags: javascript, css

I have a table inside a div of fixed size.  If the table overflows the div I would like  scrollbars to appear.  I also want to clone the header of the table for when I scroll down, so that the header is persistent.  The problem I have is that I want the horizontal scrollbar to scroll both the cloned header and the original table and the vertical scrollbar to move only the original table.

I am able to clone the header using javascript, but I am unable to style the result in a way to achieve my desired results.  Below is one attempt at the HTML/CSS assuming that the cloned header is already in place.  I get a lot of extra scrollbars, which I understand is due to the CSS spec itself.  I'm hoping there is a workaround.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <table id="headerClone">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Heading 1</th>
                <th>Heading 2</th>
                <th>Heading 3</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="tableWrapper">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Heading 1</th>
                    <th>Heading 2</th>
                    <th>Heading 3</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
#headerClone {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#tableWrapper {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/purves/Lsn8bnwr/)

Comment: This cannot be done without a little Javascript / jQuery. Are you open to that? Your question isn't tagged Javascript/jQuery, hence asking?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'm certainly open to and expected the solution to use javascript.  I updated the tags.

Comment: I have already added an answer using minimal jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need JavaScript for this.

**Snippet:**

```js
var cont= document.getElementById('container');
var head= document.getElementById('headerClone');
var wrap= document.getElementById('tableWrapper');
head.style.width= cont.clientWidth+'px';
cont.onscroll = function() {
  head.scrollLeft= this.scrollLeft;
};
```

```css
#container {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

#headerClone {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
}

#tableWrapper {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="headerClone">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Heading 1</th>
            <th>Heading 2</th>
            <th>Heading 3</th>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tableWrapper">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Heading 1</th>
                    <th>Heading 2</th>
                    <th>Heading 3</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I moved `headerClone` into a parent `div` element:

```
<div id="headerClone">
  <table>
    <tr><th>Heading 1<th>Heading 2<th>Heading 3</th>
  </table>
</div>
```

I added these styles to `headerClone`:

```
#headerClone {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Using JavaScript, I set `headerClone`'s width to match `container`'s width, and I added a scroll event on `container`, which moves `headerClone` left and right, but not up and down:

```
var cont= document.getElementById('container');
var head= document.getElementById('headerClone');
head.style.width= cont.clientWidth+'px';
cont.onscroll = function() {
  head.scrollLeft= this.scrollLeft;
};
```

Comment: I really like this answer, scrolling left/right with javascript kept the up/down scroll very smooth.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is scrollable table where header scrolls right along with the body but remains fixed when scrolling up/down.

This is not possible without a little bit of Javascript / jQuery.

What you are doing is very near to the end result. The following snippet will make it clear to you.

Just change your markup a little bit. Wrap tables in `div`s and fix up the `table` markup. Next, we need to keep the `headerClone` positioned absolutely in relation to the `container`. We also need to use the `table-layout: fixed;` to keep the tables fixed in size. Also, need to fix the size of `th` so that both the tables have same width.

That's it. Now using jQuery/Javascript, just handle the `scroll` event on the `container` and get to know how much it scrolled vertically using its `.scrollTop()`. Assign this scrolled distance to the CSS `top` property of the `headerClone`. Now the header will appear `fixed` in relation to the `container`.

One more thing remains... give the `th` some colour so that the body is not visible through it while scrolling.

***Your Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/njss2t05/2/***

***Snippet:***

```js
var $header = $("#headerClone");
$("#container").on("scroll", function() {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop() + "px";
    $header.css({"top": top, "left": "0px;"});
});
```

```css
#container {
    width: 240px; height: 160px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: auto; position: relative;
}
#headerClone { 
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; 
}
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    width: 120px; padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
th { background-color: #ddd; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="headerClone">
        <table>
            <thead><tr><th>Heading 1</th><th>Heading 2</th><th>Heading 3</th></tr></thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tableWrapper">
        <table>
            <thead><tr><th>Heading 1</th><th>Heading 2</th><th>Heading 3</th></tr></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>Data Long 1</td><td>Data Long 2</td><td>Data Long 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data Long 1</td><td>Data Long 2</td><td>Data Long 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data Long 1</td><td>Data Long 2</td><td>Data Long 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data Long 1</td><td>Data Long 2</td><td>Data Long 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data Long 1</td><td>Data Long 2</td><td>Data Long 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data Long 1</td><td>Data Long 2</td><td>Data Long 3</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great detailed answer.  Constantly adjusting the vertical scroll with javascript made the header a bit jumpy.  @RickHitchcock 's solution with fixing the vertical with absolute positioning and using javascript for horizontal scrolling was smoother for me.

Comment: @Chris: Ahh.. yes of course. I had completely ignored the flex! Thanks for pointing out. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

In the below fiddle there is horizontal scroll bar to scroll both original and cloned header 
Vertical scroll bar to scroll original header alone

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/Lsn8bnwr/1/][1]
```

Is this what you want?